# How to put horizontal scrollbar at top of extjs 3.4 grid?

Tags: extjs, extjs3, horizontal-scrolling

I've reviewed the excellent solutions to [adding top horizontal scrollbars to a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934271/horizontal-scrollbar-on-top-and-bottom-of-table/3935190#3935190) and [adding a top horizontal scrollbar to a jqgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994360/jqgrid-horizontal-scrollbar-at-top-by-header), but what about an extjs grid?

I saw a [suggestion for an extjs version 4.1+ grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317360/can-i-get-a-horizontal-scrollbar-at-the-top-and-the-bottom-of-a-grid-when-using) but it wasn't fleshed out in an example and the function referenced became available after 3.4 (which is the version I'm using).

Has anyone done this in extjs 3.x?  If so, can you provide an example please or at least explain the methodology?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Can you upload a snippet of your code? Try wrapping the Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel with the panel below, then adjust its width to accommodate all columns nicely.

```
var gridPanel = new Ext.Panel({
  width: '100%',
  height: '100%',
  renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
  autoScroll: true });
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15073110/horizontally-scrollable-grid-in-extjs-3-3) for reference.